# How to send data to lumen route

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, lumen, laravel-passport

i'm trying to send client_secret and id into oauth/token, 
this is my route

```
$router->post('api/v1/oauth/token'[
      'grant_type' => 'password',
      'client_id' => '2',
      'client_secret' => 'token',
      'username' => $request->username,
      'password'=> $request->password,
    ],function(){
  return app('auth')->user();
});
```

this is my postman
[image]
please help me

Comment: Please show how you're trying to send it.

Comment: like this ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgVwu.png

Comment: You're missing a comma after `'api/v1/oauth/token'`.